# NotesViewEntry sort items

Tags: lotus-notes, xpages-ssjs

I have following code in the data binding of a data table. I would like to sort the items (viewEntries) on part (spareProductPart) in order to display them sorted in my data table.

```
var thisDb:NotesDatabase = sessionAsSigner.getDatabase("","demo/demo.nsf");

Ventry=function(ve:NotesViewEntry){
this.prod=entry.getDocument().getItemValueString("spareProduct");
this.drawing=entry.getDocument().getItemValueString("spareDrawingNumber");
this.part=entry.getDocument().getItemValueString("spareProductPart");
this.unid=entry.getUniversalID();
etc ....
}

var viewEntries=[];
var Collection:NotesViewEntryCollection=thisDb.getView("parts").getAllEntries();
Collection.FTSearch(viewScope.toSearch);
var entry:NotesViewEntry=Collection.getFirstEntry();
while (entry!=null){ //loop over all entryes
viewEntries.push( new Ventry( entry) )
entry = Collection.getNextEntry();
}
return (viewEntries);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use NotesView's [FTSearchSorted](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.api.doc/r_domino_View_FTSearchSorted.html) instead of FTSearch.

Your code would look like this then:

```js
...
var viewEntries = [];
var viewParts:NotesView = thisDb.getView("parts");
viewParts.FTSearchSorted(viewScope.toSearch, 0, "yourSortedColumnName");
var Collection:NotesViewEntryCollection = viewParts.getAllEntries();
var entry:NotesViewEntry = Collection.getFirstEntry();
...
```

Comment: You're right once again, thank you. Now I'm left with another problem. My searchstring sometimes contains ( and ). This let's  crash the whole thing. I think I'll have to start a new thread for that.

Comment: You join different parts of your search with "and" probably. Make sure you eliminate empty parts before your join.

Answer (score 0):

"This class provides you mainly with a collection of documents in a view-sorted order."  That means if you want your viewEntryCollection sorted by the part number, your view would have to be sorted that way.  So the answer: change the view so that it's sorted by by spareProductPart

Comment: Well I thought the same , but it isn't following the order of my view , that's why I'm looking for another way to sort it

Comment: "The collection of documents that match the full-text query is sorted by relevance with highest relevance first"  That's why it's not sorted how you want.